# FilePond does not give any id on server delete file

Tags: node.js, filepond

I am trying to use FilePond, uploading is going well but I try to implement the "DELETE" feature to remove from the server unwanted file by the user. 
I've followed the documentation ( https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/ ) , my "/upload" fonction is called with a DELETE method, but no id! And I confirm that I pass the ID correctly on the client  side....

```
// Here is my node.js backed...
//
app.delete('/upload', function(req, res) {
   console.log("Delete",req.body);  // This is always empty.....
});
```

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 2):

I know this is too late, but maybe it can to help someone in the future.

FilePond send `id` of the deleting file as `text/plain`. So you need to use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#readme) before.

```
app.use(bodyParser.text());
```

Comment: For express 4.17.0 or later you can use `app.use(express.text());`.